# Difference between Rebol 2 and Rebol 3 when mixing SOME in parse with CHANGE

Tags: parsing, rebol, rebol3

Imagine a simplified example of a block of blocks containing words:

```
samples: [
    [a a c a]
    [a a c b]
    [b a c a]
    [c a c b]
    [c c c c]
]
```

Each block needs to be `[c c c c]`.  So if a value is `'a`, it is changed to `'b`.  If a value is `'b`, it is changed to `'c`.  If a value is `'c`, we print "C" and move on:

```
repeat i length? samples [
    prin ["^/Sample" i "- "]
    parse samples/:i [
        some [
            s: 'a (change s 'b) :s
            | s: 'b (change s 'c) :s
            | 'c (prin "C")
        ]
    ]
]
```

In Rebol 2, this works as expected:

```
Sample 1 - CCCC
Sample 2 - CCCC
Sample 3 - CCCC
Sample 4 - CCCC
Sample 5 - CCCC
```

But Rebol 3 seems to have a problem (bug?):

```
Sample 1 - 
Sample 2 - 
Sample 3 - 
Sample 4 - C
Sample 5 - CCCC
```

I don't know if it's related, but a Rebol Wikibook containing a list of [changes to parse between Rebol 2 and Rebol 3](http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=REBOL_Programming/Language_Features/Parse/Parse_expressions&stable=0#Differences_between_R2_and_R3_parsing) says this:

> SOME subrule - to prevent unwanted infinite loops in R3 this rule stops also when the subrule matches the input but does not advance it

*(Note: This simplified example [provided by @rgchris in StackOverflow chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7199761#7199761), repeated here to better preserve "institutional knowledge" and permit updating.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it does not actually matter whether you use ANY (0..n) or SOME (1..n), as is the case in your example, you can use WHILE in R3. WHILE basically matches R2's ANY:

```
>> blk: [a a c a]

>> parse blk [while [s: 'a (change s 'b) :s | s: 'b (change s 'c) :s | 'c]]
== true

>> blk
== [c c c c]
```

Alternatively, if that doesn't suffice because you really need SOME semantics, you could [rewrite SOME using more basic primitives](http://en.wikibooks.org/w/index.php?title=REBOL_Programming/Language_Features/Parse/Parse_expressions&stable=0#Parse_idioms). Instead of `rule: [some subrule]` you can use `rule: [subrule opt rule]`:

```
 >> blk: [a a c a]

 >> subrule: [s: 'a (change s 'b) :s | s: 'b (change s 'c) :s | 'c]     
 >> parse blk rule: [subrule opt rule]
 == true

 >> blk
 == [c c c c]
```

However, that might make you hit some PARSE limits which you won't hit with the original SOME (especially in R2).